# advtree unable to resize final column

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dotnetbar

I cannot resize the right most column in an advtree.

I have set the foloowing flags in advtree to true

```
Allowusertoreordercolumns = true
Allowusertoresizecolumns = true
Gridcolumnlineresizeenabled = true
Gridcolumnlines = true

Dragdropenabled = false
Allowdrop = false
```

I can resize the other columns and move them but i cannot resize the final column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why this is happening,

If you set

```
Gridcolumnlineresizeenabled = false
```

then it fixes the problem,

so when Gridcolumnlineresizeenabled  is true, you can resize columns be the grid lines but not the final column.